# How to set .then to var?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am trying using a package called "[app-store-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-store-scraper)"

All of the examples look something like this:

```
var store = require('app-store-scraper');

store.app({id: 553834731}).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

but all it does is print it to the console. So I was wondering how to put it into a variable?

I have tried to do `var test = store.app({id: 553834731})` but it returns nothing

Edit:
I'm using this to return like `res.end();` on a webserver.
so I'm trying to return `store.app()`

Answer (score 0):

Your function - `store.app()` returns a promise.

you can do:

```
var test = store.app({id: 553834731})
test.then(console.log);
```

in a modern async/await syntax, which is a lot easier to understand, your code can be rewritten:

```
try {
  const ret = await store.app({id: 553834731});
  console.log(ret);
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: I'm using this to return like ```res.end();``` on a webserver. and I'm very new to javascript so i dont know how async works. So to clairfy: how do i return the ```store.app()```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let result;

store.app({ id: 553834731 }).then(res => result = res).catch(console.error);
```

or

```js
const result = await store.app({ id: 553834731 });
```